# A custom RSS feed link, how do I modify the XML structure?

Tags: php, rss, feed

I'm working on this website and I can not find where I can modify it. It has a different link, than regular RSS feed links.

While a normal RSS feed looks like this

```
websiteaddress.com/?feed=rss
```

However, this project I'm working on has a different structure. The RSS feed that is used has a link, which is different:

```
websiteaddress.com/?customfeed=1
```

Both links open an RSS feed

How is this created? Where can I find it? And how can I edit it at all? Even a push in the right direction would be awesome. I've been trying to Google for the answer for a while, but I've come to a standstill. 
I've looked through the functions.php file, but nothing. I should mention this page was not created by me from the start, I'm only editing it.

I should also mention that the customfeed only accepts 1 as it's value, should I put anything else instead of it, it refuses to work and simply redirects me to the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the native feeds and those that are added in line with WP API (`add_feed()`) rely on `feed=[type]` query variable and corresponding `do_feed_{$feed}` action hook where they are executed.

From your description it's different. Someone registered entirely different query variable in code and attached their own logic to it.

There is no way to say how precisely that was done without finding and reading code responsible (searching for `customfeed` would be a start).

Comment: Thank you, I'll run a search and try to figure something out.